# What is most preferable/acceptable notation on parameterized probability distribution and expectation?

Tags: probability, notation

I am coming from machine learning community, during reading papers, different authors use different notations for parameterized probability distribution and expectation. Thus, I am quite curious to see what is most preferable or acceptable notation to recommend from mathematics community.

There are a few examples as following

1. A probability density function over $x$

   (a): $p(x)$

   (b): $P(x)$

   (c): $\mathbb{P}(x)$

   (d): $\mathrm{P}(x)$

For following questions, by default using $P(x)$.

2. Given a probability distribution $P(x)$ parameterized by a vector $\theta$.

   (a): $P(x|\theta)$, I don't like this, because it confuses with conditional probability distribution.

   (b): $P(x; \theta)$, also not a big fun of it,

   (c): $P_{\theta}(x)$, personal favorite

For following question, by default, using $P_\theta(x)$

3. Given a random variable $x$ with PDF $P(x)$ parameterized by $\theta$, the expectation operation

   (a): $E[x|\theta]$ or $\mathbb{E}[x|\theta]$

   (b): $E_\theta[x]$ or $\mathbb{E}_\theta[x]$

   (c): $E_{x\sim P_\theta(x)}[x]$ or $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_\theta(x)}[x]$

   (d): $E_{x\sim P_\theta(\cdot)}[x]$ or $\mathbb{E}_{x\sim P_\theta(\cdot)}[x]$

Comment: I think it is okay to use either or. I mean it really is open to interpretation, people will have differing views. What is extremely extremely important is not to confuse $P_\theta$ with $f_\theta$ and $F_\theta$, as that would represent the distribution of $\theta$ not $X$.

Comment: Agree with @TonyHellmuth about no fixed standard.  In Bayesian statistics $p(x), p(x|\theta)$ are common, provided it is clear from context that these refer to random variable $X$. // Otherwise $f_X(x)$ and $f_X(x|\theta)$ or $f_X(x;\theta),$ perhaps simplified to $f(x), f(x|\theta), f(x;\theta)$ if only one random variable in the discussion. Various authors prefer different amounts of space around $|$, For expectation, I have seen almost every conceivable font for $E.$ Nonstatisticians, particularly engineers, use $<X>$ instead of $E(X).$

Comment: While there is no set standard, some individual editors, proofreaders, authors, readers have **strong** preferences, so don't be surprised if you see some expressed here.